# Perl: Accessing XML::Simple values in scalar context

Tags: perl, xml-simple

Given the following [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3A%3ASimple) object how would I copy one of the key values into a scalar assignment. The output below if from `print Dumper($xmlobjectreturnedfrommodule);`.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Address2' => {},
          'City' => {},
          'EmailAddress' => {},
          'FName' => {},
          'PostalCode' => {},
          'LoginID' => {},
          'StateProvinceChoice' => {},
          'StateProvince' => {},
          'Phone' => {},
          'Country' => {},
          'Site' => {},
          'Address1' => {},
          'PhoneExt' => {},
          'LName' => {},
          'OrganizationName' => {},
          'Fax' => {}
        };
```

Normally with a `hashref` I would just using something like the following:

```
print $xmlobjectreturnedfrommodule->{'LoginID'};
```

but it is returning the following HASH(0x1e32640) instead of the keys value in the `hashref`. Is there something about `XML::Simple` that is causing this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is right. Check this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $VAR1 = {
          'LoginID' => {},
        };

print $VAR1->{LoginID};
```

**Output:**

```
HASH(0x8231818)
```

the `LoginID` is pointing to a hash reference which is essentially empty. If you modify the code as below, then you will get an empty hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $VAR1 = {
          'LoginID' => {},
        };

print Dumper ($VAR1->{LoginID});
```

**OutPut:**

```
$VAR1 = {};
```

> but it is returning the following HASH(0x1e32640) instead of the keys value in the `hashref`. Is there something about XML::Simple that is causing this or am I missing something?

The way you are printing it (`print $xmlobjectreturnedfrommodule->{'LoginID'};`), it will never return keys/values of the `hasref` irrespective of whether the `hashref` is empty or not. It will always return something like `HASH(0x1e32640)` because that's what `$xmlobjectreturnedfrommodule->{'LoginID'}` is holding. In other words, `{}` is a hash reference.

To print the keys/values, you need walk through the hash using a `for` loop and retrieve keys/values.